# Autocompleteextender control taking so much time on server to bind database values

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, asp.net-ajax

I have used auto complete extender with service method in cs to search values(id & name) from database in form on server & displays selected values(name) in check box list. Its working fine on local with fast speed, but on server its taking so much time to get values from database & once value selected from auto complete extender target text box then after some time value displayed in checkboxlist. I want to do it very fast same as local.
I used following code :

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hdfvalue1" onvaluechanged="hdfvalue1_ValueChanged" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"  autocomplete="off" Width="31.6%" ></asp:TextBox>
<div id="divwidth" >
</div>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="Searchmethod1" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="textbox1" ID="autocomplete1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="true" 
    CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender" CompletionListElementID="divwidth" 
    OnClientItemSelected="OnSelected"> 
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   function OnSelected (source, eventArgs) {        
        var hdfvalueID = "<%= hdfvalue1.ClientID %>";
        document.getElementById(hdfvalueID).value = eventArgs.get_value();
        __doPostBack(hdfvalueID, ""); 
   } 
</script>
```

I have used c# 3.5 version with `MS-SQL`. 
Please help me to solve above problem.
Thank You.

Comment: Can you please check the timing of getting the data from DB alone.I mean test the service alone with the input you give from UI. May be that is causing the Delay.

Comment: i have tested with different inputs but its taking same time(delay time)

Comment: if you have tested the service alone (either by wcftestclient or other means) and service is taking time then you should have a look at tuning the service code or the Corresponding SQL code.

Comment: @kishoreVM not tested with tools...please guide me what exactly to do?? Test service alone means exactly what?

Comment: I mean to say is check how much time Searchmethod1 is taking In each environment for the same input ( you can log it the duration before the DB call abd After DB call). Normally the delay is expected from loaclly executed code, as your code needs to connect to differnt machine to get the data network latecncy is expected. Also your local DB might have few records hence Query is faster in local Environment. May be on server you have much more data and resulting in the longer query execution.(if this is the case you may need to change MinimumPrefixLength to more so that less records are fectched

Comment: Or you may need to look for other tuning options such as Indexing the column involved in the search.

Answer (score 0):

In Autocomplete Extender you are calling server side method which will always take more time.

For Auto complete you must use javascript or jquery plugin like

"http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/" for auto complete